# XMLReader вытащить значения при разных аргументах

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser

Подскажите, как вытащить значения (напр. 24, 006533) с помощью XMLReader из определенных строк, как например эти:

```
<param name="Гарантия, срок (мес)">24</param>
<param name="Артикул">006533</param>
```

То есть я хотел бы вытащить со строк только с определенным name. Порядок может отличаться, имена - нет.

Ниже - так как я тащу другие значения например из

```
<?
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($contents);
$flag = true;
while($xml->read() && $xml->name !== 'offer');
  while($xml->name === 'offer'){
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
    $name = $node->name;
    $picture = $node->picture;
    $price = $node->price;
//дальше что-то делаем
?>
```

Общая структура XML: http://www.tss.ru/bitrix/catalog_export/yandex_800463.xml

Comment: и почему бы сразу не использовать SimpleXML, зачем смешивать?

Comment: объём файла может быть очень большим. XMLReader работает с этим лучше, как я читал.

Comment: очень большой это сколько в вашем понимании? если 5 мегабайт, то это одно, если 125 или 2 гига, это другое. по вашей ссылке просто файл маленький, поэтому и спросил. В любом случае несколько странно смешивать sax и dom подход одновременно, но в принципе, почему бы и нет.

Comment: Да, в том-то и дело, что файлы БД XML обычно могут быть до нескольких ГБ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XMLReader для перемещения по документу использует курсор, поэтому когда ты натолкнулся на узел типа `XMLReader::ELEMENT`, нужно передвинуть курсор еще раз. Если узел оказался типа `XMLReader::TEXT`, то это и есть значение.

Выглядит это примерно так:
`[XMLReader::ELEMENT]XMLReader::TEXT[/XMLReader::ELEMENT]`

Так что в твоем схема следующая:

Обходим все узлы

Находим узлы типа `XMLReader::ELEMENT`

Если у узла `localName == 'param'`, то получаем аттрибут "name" (метод `getAttribute()`)

Если "name" среди нужных нам, продвигаем курсор и забираем текст

Вот пример скрипта, который собирает параметры по офферам:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('http://www.tss.ru/bitrix/catalog_export/yandex_800463.xml');

//значения name у <param> которые нужно найти
$arParamNames = [
    'Гарантия, срок (мес)',
    'Напряжение (В)'
];

$arParsedData = [];

//чтение документа
while ($reader->read()) {
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

        //если элемент <offer>, получаем аттрибут "id" 
        if ($reader->localName == 'offer') {
            $currentOfferId = $reader->getAttribute('id');
        }

        //если элемент <param>
        if ($reader->localName == 'param') {

            //проверяем есть ли значение "name" среди искомых 
            if (in_array($reader->getAttribute('name'),$arParamNames)) {

                $currentParam = $reader->getAttribute('name');

                //читаем дальше для получения текста в <param></param>
                $reader->read();
                if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
                    $arParsedData[$currentOfferId][$currentParam] = $reader->value;
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arParsedData);
echo '</pre>';
```